# Deleting primary key in Room

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to set my primary key to one after deleting all items in table:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM myTable")
fun deleteTable()

@Query("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'myTable'")
fun clearPrimaryKey()
```

but it doesn't work and after adding items again, their number don't start from 1. Any idea how to clear primary key in Room library?

Comment: You want to reset the primary key number??

Comment: yes, primary key in 'myTable'

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: did it help you??

Answer (score -1):

Let us say your table name is `myTable`. Then just do this:

```
@Query("ALTER TABLE myTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1")
fun clearPrimaryKey()
```

It resets the number of auto-generated primary key.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to do both deleting and resetting is this:

```
@Query("TRUNCATE TABLE myTable;")
fun deleteAndResetPrimaryKey()
```